# OpenGL 2D light rays from texture background

Tags: opengl, jogl

I am working on OpenGL 2D image viewer for microscopic tissue investigation. I have to simulate the tissue back light in the microscope. In microscope, there is a back light on which the tissue slide is positioned. This gives a bright view of the tissue. The back light rays are almost parallel for the tissue viewport.

For my image viewer, I am rendering image tiles as textures. But not getting how to simulate the back light. I tried OpenGL diffuse light but it is not giving back light experience. Thing that I don't understand is how to place the light source in the texture background. My viewer is just 2D viewer.

Comment: It's hard to help without a picture of what the input and output are supposed to look like.

Comment: Basically I want to simulate a back light in OpenGL 2D. It should give a feeling like a parallel white light rays coming from back of the texture object.  Is it possible with 2D?

Comment: I have no idea what that is actually supposed to look like.  Picture, please.